# How to only capture the matching side of a disjunction?

Tags: python, regex

The following code:

```
re.findall('(a).(b)|(c).(d)','axbcyd')
```

Captures two matches, both with two empty strings:

```
[('a', 'b', '', ''), ('', '', 'c', 'd')]
```

I'd like to instead return:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Essentially, only capture on the side of the disjunction that actually matches. How can I do this? Happy with a totally different approach...

Comment: just remove the empty elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Avinash Raj says; just remove the empty elements:

```
map(lambda x: tuple(filter(lambda y: y!='',x)),re.findall('(a).(b)|(c).(d)','axbcyd'))
```

(Edit: Less functional, more pythonic:

```
[tuple(y for y in x if y != '') for x in re.findall('(a).(b)|(c).(d)','axbcyd')]
```

)

Comment: thanks, good idea. out of curiosity, any way to do it purely with the regex?

Comment: Only if you're fine with finding `a.d`, too: `re.findall('(a|c).(b|d)','axbcyd')`. Otherwise it's probably impossible, because the group index is determined independent of the input string.